# Typescript: could be instantiated with an arbitrary type

Tags: typescript

Hello I'm trying to work with ddd, but I'm having a problem modeling a mapper to return an instance of my domain after operations on the database with ts:

this is my domain:

```
export interface ILocationProps {
  stret_address: string;
  cep_code: CepCode;
}
export class LocationSeats extends AggregateRoot<ILocationProps> {
  get StretAddress(): string {
    return this.props.stret_address;
  }
  get CepCode(): CepCode {
    return this.props.cep_code;
  }
  private constructor(props: ILocationProps, id?: UniqueEntityID) {
    super(props, id);
  }
  public static create(
    props: ILocationProps,
    id?: UniqueEntityID,
  ): Result<LocationSeats> {
    const guardedProps = [
      { argument: props.cep_code, argumentName: 'cep_code' },
      { argument: props.stret_address, argumentName: 'stret_address' },
    ];

    const guardResult = Guard.againstNullOrUndefinedBulk(guardedProps);

    if (!guardResult.succeeded) {
      return Result.fail<LocationSeats>(guardResult.message);
    }

    const location = new LocationSeats(props, id);

    const idWasProvided = !!id;

    if (!idWasProvided) {
      location.when(new LocationCreatedEvent(location));
    }

    return Result.ok<LocationSeats>(location);
  }
}
```

and this is my mapper:

```
export default interface IMapperr<T> {
  toPersistence(t: any): Result<T>;
  toDomain(raw: any): Result<T>;
}
@singleton()
export class LocationMapper<Location = LocationSeats> implements IMapper<Location> {
  constructor() {}
  public toPersistence(t: any) {
    throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
  }
  private validate() {}
  public toDomain(raw: any): Result<Location> {
    const cepCodeorError = CepCode.create(raw.cep_code);
    const locationOrError = LocationSeats.create(
      {
        cep_code: cepCodeorError.getValue(),
        stret_address: raw.street_address,
      },
      new UniqueEntityID(raw.id),
    );
    return locationOrError;
  }
}
```

and this is my result class:

```
export class Result<T> {
  public isSuccess: boolean;

  public isFailure: boolean;

  public error?: T | string;

  private _value?: T;

  constructor(isSuccess: boolean, error?: T | string, value?: T) {
    if (isSuccess && error) {
      throw new Error(
        'InvalidOperation: A result cannot be successful and contain an error',
      );
    }
    if (!isSuccess && !error) {
      throw new Error(
        'InvalidOperation: A failing result needs to contain an error message',
      );
    }

    this.isSuccess = isSuccess;
    this.isFailure = !isSuccess;
    this.error = error;
    this._value = value;

    Object.freeze(this);
  }

  getValue(): T {
    if (!this.isSuccess) {
      console.log(this.error);

      throw new Error(
        "Can't get the value of an error result. Use 'errorValue' instead.",
      );
    }
    if (!this._value)
      throw new Error(
        "Can't get the value of an error result. Use 'errorValue' instead.",
      );
    return this._value;
  }

  errorValue(): T {
    return this.error as T;
  }

  static ok<U>(value?: U): Result<U> {
    return new Result<U>(true, undefined, value);
  }

  static fail<U>(error: any): Result<U> {
    return new Result<U>(false, error);
  }

  static combine(results: Result<any>[]): Result<any> {
    for (const result of results) {
      if (result.isFailure) return result;
    }
    return Result.ok();
  }
}
```

but i got this error:

on my toDomain function:

```
 public toDomain(raw: any): Result<Location> {
    const cepCodeorError = CepCode.create(raw.cep_code);
    const locationOrError = LocationSeats.create(
      {
        cep_code: cepCodeorError.getValue(),
        stret_address: raw.street_address,
      },
      new UniqueEntityID(raw.id),
    );
    return locationOrError;
  }
```

error:

```
Type 'Result<LocationSeats>' is not assignable to type 'Result<Location>'.
  Type 'LocationSeats' is not assignable to type 'Location'.
    'Location' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'LocationSeats'.ts(2322)
```

I have no idea why my create function returns a type: Result

Comment: Where does the error occur? And try to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It's hard to find the relevant code in all of this. For instance you could put it into the typescript playground and then reduce the code to the relevant parts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have tagged `toDomain` as returning a `Location` which is a template argument with no constraint, but then you've hard coded it to return `LocationSeats.create`. Typescript doesn't know if `LocationSeats.create` will be compatible with whatever generic type you might choose to pass for `Location`.

The problem of designing factory functions that are generic on the type being constructed often trip up people new to Typescript. The reason is usually, unlike in some other languages, the generic type parameters are not available as runtime objects on which you can call static methods such as your `create` method. They are completely erased at runtime.

In Typescript, to create a generic factory, you must actually pass a constructor reference to your factory at runtime.

Something like this might be close to what you are going for (stripped down a bit to show the parts I want to highlight):

```
class LocationSeats extends AggregateRoot<ILocationProps> {
  private constructor (props: ILocationProps, id?: UniqueEntityID) {
    super(props, id)
  }

  static create (props: ILocationProps, id?: UniqueEntityID): Result<LocationSeats> {
    return Result.ok(new LocationSeats(props, id))
  }
}

// We need an explicit factory interface for creating these objects
interface LocationCreator<T> {
  create (props: ILocationProps, id?: UniqueEntityID): Result<T>
}

class LocationMapper<Location> {
  // Need to accept the Location creator at runtime (Location is inferred)
  constructor (private creator: LocationCreator<Location>) {}

  toDomain (): Result<Location> {
    return this.creator.create({
        cep_code: '',
        stret_address: '',
      })
  }
}

// Need to pass the LocationSeats constructor in at runtime
const mapper = new LocationMapper(LocationSeats)
```

Comment: that solved it, but I was left with a doubt:
how to make an abstraction?

If not, I would have to create an interface for each factory, that is, I would have to have more than 10: interface to create instance.

Comment: thanks for the help, if you can shed some light on this issue

Comment: @GabrielCosta You'll have to give me more detail. If you can write want you want in pseudo code I will have a look at it.

Comment: excuse is because my english is a little bad, but basically with this solution i need to have an interface for each domain i wanted something that was just 1 interface for all domains would that be possible?

Comment: @GabrielCosta As I said, I don't have enough information to answer.  I don't know anything about your "domains" or how you want to use them. I can't design your abstraction for you. If you design the abstraction you want in either pseudo code or in a different language that you are comfortable with then I can help you convert it to typescript.